# Regex to Find a Word Inside Curly Braces

Tags: regex, textmate, oniguruma

I need a way to search the text using RegEx and find a word thats inside Latex command (which means that it's inside curly braces)

Here is the example:

```
Tarzan is my name and everyone knows that {Tarzan loves Jane}
```

Now if you search for regex: `({[^{}]*?)(Tarzan)([^}]*})` and replace it with `$1T~a~r~z~a~n$3`

This will replace only the word Tarzan inside curly braces and ignore the other instance! This is as far as I came.

Now what I need is something to do the same with the following example:

```
Tarzan is my name and everyone knows that {Tarzan loves Jane} but she doesn't know that because its written with \grk{Tarzan loves Jane}
```

In this example I need just the last mention of "Tarzan" to be replaced (the one within \grk{})

Can someone help me to modify the above RegEx search to do only that?

Comment: What language do you use? Note that your pattern will not work if the target word occurs several times between the same brackets. Do you want to replace the last occurrence of the target word or the one between `\grk{.....}`?

Comment: I dont need any language. I will use regular expressions search and replace in text editor (Textmate on Mac). I think that uses Oniguruma regular expression library.

Comment: In this case, add the correct tag to your question.

Comment: Which tag is correct? Because I used regex string and latex tags and they all seem correct to me

Comment: What is the desired behaviour if several target words are inside the `\grk{...}`?

Comment: Ideal would be to replace all of them but thats not necessary because I can run this multiple times which will replace them all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102725/discussion-between-eklisiarh-and-casimir-et-hippolyte).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use this pattern:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\\grk{)[^}]*?\KTarzan
```

[demo](http://rubular.com/r/MkDl3xaOd3)

details:

```
(?:
    \G(?!\A)  # contiguous to a previous match
  |           # OR
    \\grk{    # first match
)
[^}]*?        # all that is not a } (non-greedy) until ...
\K            # reset the start of the match at this position
Tarzan        # ... the target word
```

Note: `\G` matches the position after the previous match, but it matches the start of the string too. That's with I add `(?!\A)` to prevent a match at the start of the string.

Or you can use: `\\grk{[^}]*?\KTarzan` with multiple pass.

Comment: That worked! Incredible! Thank you so much! Can you just tell me what tags should I put below the original question so that others find it easier?